# Why does Julia DIct.keys show a power of 2 values

Tags: dictionary, julia

using Julia 0.6.2

when i create a dictionary of 10 items, the array for the keys is 16, apparently rounding up to the next power of 2.

`julia> dk.keys
16-element Array{Int64,1}:
   0
   4
   9
  25
 100
  81
   0
   0
  16
  36
  64
   0
  49
   0
   0
   1`

when i create a dictionary with 17 keys

```
julia> dkk = Dict(k^2 => "*"^k for k = 1:17)
```

Dict{Int64,String} with 17 entries:

...

```
julia> dkk.keys
64-element Array{Int64,1}:
          0
          0
        100
          0
        121
         81
          0
          0
         16
          0
          ⋮
 4536409040
 4536409456
         36
        225
        256
          0
          0
 4536409904
          1
```

why 64 instead of the next power of 2, which would be 32?

either way, i really just want the keys and not the hash table.

note: when the dictionary is access directly, the number of entries is what i'd expect.

```
julia> dk
```

Dict{Int64,String} with 10 entries:

```
julia> dkk
```

Dict{Int64,String} with 17 entries:

Comment: base/dict.js is where Dicts are defined. Note `_tablesz` and `n = 16`.

Comment: .js ?  is this in julia?

Comment: .jl. Yes, it's in Julia.

Comment: ok, @JulianFondren   found it:  `_tablesz(x::Integer) = x < 16 ? 16 : one(x)<<((sizeof(x)<<3)-leading_zeros(x-1))` [base/dict.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/dict.jl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's powers of 2 for some internal reason (which I would guess is due to using a tree or something like that, I don't know). Avoid directly grabbing internals. Instead, use the iterator `keys(dk)`. If you want the keys as an array, use `collect(keys(dk))`.

Comment: OK. makes sense.  i had tried julia> collect(dk.keys)
which gives 16-element Array{Int64,1}